# using a click listen in angular inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

how do I keep this function from firing/incrementing every single div generated? I only want it to upvote the specific one that I click on. I think the problem is that is inside the ng-repeat.

```
<div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
                  <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes()">

                    {{value[0]}} and {{value[1]}} for {{value[2]}} and {{value[3]}} upvotes: {{upvotes}}
                  </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you want the functionality to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is have the function in your controller handle the incrementing of the upvotes, not the actual DOM. Then you can pass in which value you want to be incremented through that function. For example your controller could look like:

```
function incrementUpvotes(valueNumber){
    $scope.value[valueNumber]++;
}
```

and your HTML like:

```
<div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
    <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes(value)">{{value[0]}} and {{value[1]}} for {{value[2]}} and {{value[3]}}       upvotes: {{upvotes}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea but I did exactly as you said and it's not working.. :-(